# processing error (It looks like you're mixing "active" and "static" modes.)

Tags: processing

It looks like you're mixing "active" and "static" modes. I want to play two figures different direction. I am a beginner and need help in understanding what to do wiht the error.

```
int x,y;
int diam;
int xdir;
int z,r;
int zdir;
int extent;

void setup(){
  size(600, 400);
  x = 300;
  y = 100;
  diam = 30;
  xdir = +4;
  fill(#000000);
  z = 300;
  r = 300;
  zdir = -4;
  extent = 30;
}
void draw(){
  background(200);
  ellipse(x, y, diam, diam);
  x = x + xdir;
  if (x + diam/2 > 600){
     xdir = xdir * -1; 
     fill(#e81919);
  }
   else if (x - diam/2 < 0 ){
      xdir = xdir * -1;
      fill(#00f22e);
    }
  }
  square (z, r, extent);
  z = z + zdir;
  if (z + 30 > 600 || z - 30 < 0){
    zdir = zdir * -1;
    fill(#00f22e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra curly brace after else if (){}.  Should look like this:

```
void draw() {
  background(200);
  ellipse(x, y, diam, diam);
  x = x + xdir;
  if (x + diam/2 > 600) {
    xdir = xdir * -1;
    fill(#e81919);
  } else if (x - diam/2 < 0 ) {
    xdir = xdir * -1;
    fill(#00f22e);
  }
  square (z, r, extent);
  z = z + zdir;
  if (z + 30 > 600 || z - 30 < 0) {
    zdir = zdir * -1;
    fill(#00f22e);
  }
}
```